# Does the verb "Unstar" exist?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

I'm creating an application for the iPhone where the user has the ability to *star* an item, i.e. adding a star to the item. Now I am wondering whether I can also use *unstar*? Or should I go with something different - if so, what?

Comment: What is the purpose of 'starring'? Does it denote something, i.e. a favourite thing? Is it an actual star you are using or an asterisk (*)?

Comment: If your users understand *star* as a verb that means something like  "add to favorite list", I'm sure that they would understand *unstar* as "remove from favorite list"

Comment: @Bruno - is there a distinction between un-star and *de-star* in this sense?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Yes, it is an actual star. The app shows a nice image.

Comment: Verbing nouns weirds the language. Unverbing them is worse yet.

Comment: So you want to De-Unverb the language, dbkk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb *to unstar* is not reported in the dictionary I have, which doesn't report *to unpublish* either.

If *to star* refers to an action that changes the status of something, then *to unstar* would be understood as the action that makes the opposite status change.

This is what happens with *to unpublish*, which is understood as *to change the status to not published*.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I am going to use it now. Thanks!

Comment: My dictionary also does not have *unpublish*, but it does have *unpublished* and *unpublishable*.

Comment: @GEdgar Both the terms are reported from the NOAD too, but they are adjectives.

Comment: @GEdgar: there is a little difference there. *Unpublished* and *unpublishable*, can be used when speaking about printed press, and refer to the fact that an article/text has not been published yet (or it is too bad to be published). In printed press there is no way to *unpublish* something once it is published. *Unpublish* specifically refers to some sort of electronic publication, where the "publication status" of an item can be reversed.

Answer (score 6):

*Unstar* is commonly used in applications such as Gmail. I would say yes, it's acceptable to use in the context of software.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about unstar but you can definitely use Unstarred as gmail and other e-mail provider use in there action buttons

Comment: That is true, but unhelpful. "Un-" is a much more productive prefix with adjectives (including participles) than it is with verbs. Examples with adjectives: "unwritten, unheard, un-English, undifferentiated, unusual, unsubtle, unbeaten, unamusing". With verbs, as Whorf pointed out, it is mostly limited to verbs of fastening or enclosing: "untie, unwrap, unlock, unstrap, unroll". There have always been a few notable exceptions such as "unsay" (which is archaic); but I think that the verbal prefix has been broadening its range in the last few decades, as here.

Comment: @Colin I think what is happening is verbalization of the adjectives rather than use of the prefix "un" with verbs. "star" (mark with a star) -> "starred" (marked with a star) -> "unstarred" (not marked with a star) -> "unstar" (to make not marked with a star) rather than "star" (mark with a star) => "unstar" (make not marked with a star).

Comment: @Nohat - I think you're right. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is obvious that "to unstar" something is to set a value to 0 that was once a 1, with a star icon displayed, but if you read the linked question there seems to be a bit of confusion in the general public as to how "to star" should be interpreted as a verb.

basically, "star" is not a verb, so neither is "unstar" but if you do decide to use one as a verb you might as well use the other to be consistent.

you'd be safer using actual verbs from the dictionary, saying "remove a star" alongside a clear concept of what "adding a star" means.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really difficult to say "remove a star", which all readers will understand instantly, without needing to refer to a glossary?

Whether or not this activity requires the inclusion of a new word in the English language remains to be seen, but it isn't there yet, so why make life difficult for yourself?   Fretting over it has probably taken up much more of your time and energy than typing the extra few characters would have.

Just use words that say what you mean, and will be understood by your readers -- i.e. in this case, if you're writing for GMail users, go ahead and use "unstar"; if you're not, consider using real words.

Comment: Software does not always follow standard language rules. Oftentimes shorter is better.

Comment: In the code, sure, but when explaining to a user how to use something, code-style shortcuts are usually best avoided (unless you enjoy getting bugs because they've misunderstood and screwed it up).

Comment: true, in documentation a longer explanation is definitely better